# How to create objects with a list of optional elements from a dictionary?

Tags: python

I've been learning how to program and this is problem I'm having trouble solving:

I have a class User that takes 4 parameters, 2 required and 2 optional:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user_id, first_name, last_name='', username=''):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.username = username
```

then I make a function to create those objects, they take a dictionary and  use looks in the keys to create the objects

```
users={}


def user_register(user_info):
if user_info['id'] in users:
    pass
else:
    print('cadastrando...')
    users[user_info['id']] = User(user_info['id'], user_info['first_name'],
                                  user_info['last_name'], user_info['username'])

example_userinfo1 = {'id':111, 'first_name':'john', 'last_name':'smith', 'username':'@johnsmith'}

example_userinfo2 = {'id':222, 'first_name':'bob'}
```

so like this it only works if the dictionary given has all the four keys,which is the case of example_userinfo1, but not the case for example_userinfo2 (only ID and first_name are mandatory). I would like to know what is the way of checking if the key exists before passing it as an argument, I tried something like this with no success:

```
User(user_info['id'], user_info['first_name'],
        if 'last_name' in user_info: last_name=user_info['last_name'],
        if 'username' in user_info: username=user_info['username'])
```

so what is a good way to overcome this problem? also I would like to know if there are many signs of bad practices on my code (as I am trying to start paying attention to those things)

Comment: last_name=user_info['last_name'] if 'last_name' in user_info else None

Comment: @Shasha99: the class sets missing keyword arguments to `''`. And why use a conditional expression when you could just use `dict.get()`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, he actually was trying to use this conditional assignment, So i was just letting him know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your dictionary keys correspond dir to the argument names, just apply the whole dictionary as keyword arguments:

```
user_id = user_info.pop('id')
users[user_id]  = User(user_id, **user_info)
```

I used `dict.pop()` to remove the `'id'` key as your class expects `user_id` instead. You already supplied default values for any missing keys.

Otherwise, you could have used `dict.get()` to return an empty string if a key is missing:

```
User(user_info['id'], user_info['first_name'],
    last_name=user_info.get('last_name', ''),
    username=user_info.get('username', ''))
```

Comment: Except `id` in the dict needs to be `user_id` or change the arg name to `id`.

Comment: @AChampion: ah, missed that. Adjusted.

Comment: thanks, both solutions are great and work really well for what I want. I decided to go for the second one, because the dictionaries are in fact provided by and API (this is for a telegram bot) and maybe they would add extra keys to their users in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this is to unpack the `dict` using `**`. For example:

```
>>> userinfo = {'user_id':222, 'first_name':'bob'}
#                  ^  I am using `user_id` instead of `id`. 
#                     Continue reading for explanation
>>> User(**userinfo)
<__main__.User instance at 0x7f1f4c70cf80>
```

When you unpack the dict within the function call, it maps the `dict` key with the function parameters and the dict value as the value of parameter. So in this case, your function call was like:

```
User(user_id=222, first_name='bob')
```

---

**Edit:** Based on additional information from user as `id` is returned from API. And it is not good to use `id` as variable since [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) is built-in function in python. In this case, you can modify `dict` explicitly as:

```
>>> userinfo = {'id':222, 'first_name':'bob'}
>>> userinfo['user_id'] = userinfo['id']
>>> del userinfo['id']
>>> userinfo
{'first_name': 'bob', 'user_id': 222}   # Final value hold by dict
```

Comment: I can't change the dictionaries (they are provided by an API), and I think using as `id` as a variable is not a good idea, because this is a function name, right?

Comment: @phbrasiliano Check my edit. Yes, you should not use `id` as parameter. But you can rename the `key` in your original dict

Comment: Even better to create a dict to map the `key` of your api dict with the value you want to pass as `key` as to your function. Create a new dict based on this mapping. It will be infact more generic